# How do I replicate some of the features of Ruby's StringScanner in R?

Tags: ruby, regex, r, tokenize, text-processing

I'm interested in porting a text tokenizer from Ruby to R, and I can't just call the Ruby scanner from within R using the `system()` function.  The existing Ruby implementation makes heavy use of some of the methods in Ruby's [`StringScanner`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html) class, and I need to figure out how to do the same thing in R.

Imagine that a string is a stream with a pointer initially pointing to the start of the string; the four operations I need are:

- `scan`: If the stream currently matches a specified regex, pull it out, or return NULL.
- `scan_until`: Move through the stream until a specified regex matches. (I don't need the intervening text, but Ruby returns it)
- `getch`: Move the stream forward one character and return it.
- `eos?`: Return true if the pointer is at the end of the stream.

I'm not picky about what the underlying object is representing the stream in R; a string would be fine, but operating on a file connection would be nice.

Comment: It seems like these behaviors are similar to the mechanisms and functions of "connection" objects in R. However, things get messy when you try to match a regular expression since you potentially always have to have the entire string available since most matches are by default greedy.

Comment: Good point; permitting an arbitrary regex does require arbitrarily long look ahead.  I may slap together an S4 class that wraps a string and a pointer index, and forget working with a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This made me realize how bad I am at designing S3 classes, but here are some functions that seem to do what you ask

```
getStringScanner <- function(text) {
    structure(list2env(list(text=text, pos=1)),
    class="StringScanner")
}

remaining <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(is(x, "StringScanner"))
    substr(x$text, x$pos, nchar(x$text))
}
restart <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(is(x, "StringScanner"))
    x$pos = 1
}

scan_here<-function(x, re, ...) {
    stopifnot(is(x, "StringScanner"))
    t <- remaining(x)
    m <- regexpr(re, t, ...)
    if(m==1) {
        x$pos = x$pos + attr(m, "match.length")
        regmatches(t,m)
    } else {
        NA
    }
}

scan_until<-function(x, re, ...) {
    stopifnot(is(x, "StringScanner"))
    t <- remaining(x)
    m <- regexpr(re, t, ...)
    if(m>0) {
        x$pos = x$pos + m  -1;
        substr(t, 1, m-1)
    } else {
        NA
    }
}

getch <- function(x, n=1) {
    stopifnot(is(x, "StringScanner"))
    r <- substr(remaining(x), 1, n)
    x$pos = x$pos + n
    r
}

is.eos <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(is(x, "StringScanner"))
    x$pos > nchar(x$text)
}
```

I did rename `scan` to `scan_here` because there is already a base function by that name and it is not generic. I also added in function to reset the parsing and extract the remaining string.

Here's a sample use session

```
ss <- getStringScanner("Start-Ok-begin-1-2-3-Start")
scan_here(ss, "Start-")
# [1] "Start-"
remaining(ss)
# [1] "Ok-begin-1-2-3-Start"
scan_until(ss, "-2-")
# [1] "Ok-begin-1"
remaining(ss)
# [1] "-2-3-Start"
getch(ss, 2)
# [1] "-2"
getch(ss)
# [1] "-"
remaining(ss)
# [1] "3-Start"
is.eos(ss)
# [1] FALSE
scan_here(ss, "3-Start")
# [1] "3-Start"
is.eos(ss)
# [1] TRUE
```

Hopefully this can at least give you a starting point. Note that the only thing "special" here is really the use of the `environment` in the representation of the `StringScanner` class. This allows me to update the `pos` value "in-place".

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I'm accepting this answer, and will give you a vote when I get enough reputation. ;)